# Move Image on Audio Play

Tags: javascript, html, animation, audio

Javascript Question here:
Is there a way to have a picture move or really trigger any other event when the user presses the play button on the audio.

My Code:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lc7ccjf6/

```css
.hero {
 width: 600px;
 height: 600px;
}
.home.hero {
 background-image: url(http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/111017060721-giant-panda-bamboo-story-top.jpg);
 background-size: cover;


}
```

```html
 <a class="scroll" id="home"></a>
 <div class="home hero">
 <script>

  $(".home").animate({"top": "+=50px"}, 400);

     </script>
   <!--audio-->
   <!--set Volume -->
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function setVolume()
    {
        mySound=document.getElementById("sound");
        mySound.volume=0.5;
    }
    window.onload=setVolume;
    </script>
            <!--Volume end-->
  <div class="audio">
     <audio id ="sound" controls>
        
        <source src="http://www.sousound.com/music/healing/healing_01.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" volume="0.5">
             Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
            
        <!--audio end-->
</div>
```

I want the picture to move down a short distance and when it reaches the bottom, come back up to the top and keep doing that so long as the audio is playing.  Any idea how to do dis?

Comment: I've tried variations of:         <script type="text/javascript">
          move=document.getElementById("home");      
        move.onplaying=function()
                 {
     $(".home").animate({height:"300px"}, 400);
                 }
        </script>

and
<script>

  $(".home").animate({"top": "+=50px"}, 400);

     </script>

Comment: Did you inlcude a jQuery library? It isn't included in the jsfiddle or in the code in your post.

Comment: I have <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Load jCarousel js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jcarousel.js"></script>
<!-- Load MixItUup js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mixitup.js"></script>
<!-- Load js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>

Comment: Here's a clue. `move` = home. `home` = anchor tag. Why do you have `move.onplaying` ? Anchor tags don't play audio so trying to attach an event listener of `onplaying` isn't going to trigger... I believe the event you want to listen for is `onplay=function(){//event code};` or `addEventListener("play", function(){//event code});` but you will need to attach that to the audio tag, not the anchor tag. (Related to the comment "I've tried variations of:")

Comment: I changed my code but I still can't get it to work, I wanted to see if my function was working so inserted an alert in there but it never called both alerts, not sure how to fix it: https://jsfiddle.net/Lc7ccjf6/3/

Answer (score 0):

personally, I prefer "play" event over "playing"( [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265332/html5-play-event-vs-playing-event-in-video-tag) SO answer gives the differences between them), in your fiddle demo, I did not find the JQuery library, so added it and cleaned up the code a bit, updated code:

```
$(function(){

    var aud = $("#sound"),            
        move=$(".home");      

    move.animate({"top": "+=50px"}, 400);                        
    aud.on('play',function() { 
        move.animate({height:"300px"}, 400); 
    });
    aud.on('pause',function() { 
        if(aud[0].paused && (aud[0].currentTime === 0 || aud[0].currentTime === aud[0].duration) ) // checking if audio is finished, not just paused in between
            move.animate({height:"600px"}, 400);
    });
});
```

### [updated fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lc7ccjf6/7/)